# Docker compose detect which services changed and update only those

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Suppose we have a `docker-compose.yml` like this one

```
services:
  serviceA:
    image: serviceA/serviceA
    hostname: ${HOSTNAME}
    environment:
      - WHATEVER=${VALUE}
    volumes:
      - ./hello/there:/general/kenobi
      - ./${PARAMETRIZED_DIR}:/something
  
  serviceB:
    image: serviceB/serviceB
    environment:
      - VARIABLE=${TEST}

  serviceC:
    image: serviceC/serviceC
```

We then update some stuff. Let's say we update the variable `HOSTNAME` from `serviceA` and we add a new environment variable to `serviceB` and also we delete `serviceC`

```
services:
  serviceA:
    image: serviceA/serviceA
    hostname: ${HOSTNAME} # This got updated in the .env file
    environment:
      - WHATEVER=${VALUE}
    volumes:
      - ./hello/there:/general/kenobi
      - ./${PARAMETRIZED_DIR}:/something
  
  serviceB:
    image: serviceB/serviceB
    environment:
      - VARIABLE=${TEST}
      - ANOTHER=${TEST2}
```

What I want to do is to run a command so Docker recreates `serviceA` and `serviceB` because got updated and deletes `serviceC`, but if some other services were running, keep them running and don't stop them. Is this possible? Are there limitations to what can docker compose do in these situations?